# What's the difference between the fields "name" and "solution name" when adding a solution in Monodevelop

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

[image: Monodevelop screenshot]

When you fill out the name in the "add new solution"-wizard in Monodevelop, the field "solution name" gets automatically filled out to the same thing, but the wizard allows you to override this default to something else. Why are there two fields to start with? How are these settings used, other then for laying down the folder hierarchy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a new project, Monodevelop will create a new solution including a new project. A solution can have more than one project. So if you would e.g. write a library and a test project for it, you could make your solution name "foo", your primary project name "libfoo" and then add the test project "footest".